# Sequelize JS, findOne only if many-to-many related entity exists

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to **find an item by two identifiers**. One identifier is the primary key of that item, another identifier is the primary key of another item from different table, that has many-to-many relation with the first one. I expect the request to return data only in case when there is an item with `id1` and there is a relation with existing item from different table with `id2`.

```
const Item1 = sequelize.define('item1', {})
const Item2 = sequelize.define('item2', {})
const Relation = sequelize.define('relation', {})

Item2.belongsToMany(Item1, { through: Relation })

// the givens are id1 of Item1 and id2 of related Item2

const data = await Item1.findOne({
    where: { id: id1 },
    include: [
        {
            model: Item2,
            attributes: [],
            required: true,
            through: {
                attributes: [],
                where: { item2Id: id2 }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

By setting `attributes` to an empty array I expect the ORM not to fetch any related data as my only concern is that the related object exists.

**Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?**

Cheers

Comment: short answer, no. you already did it in right way.

Comment: @VivekDoshi Alright then. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @DmytroY. Excuse me, I thought that you pass empty array in include[].attributes and it does not work. I can delete my answer. This sample query is more flexible.

Comment: @Faris No worries. Let's keep it as an alternative, someone may find it more suitable for their needs 

Answer (score 1):

1. I think that we can add PR with this feature.
2. Now you can do this:

   ```
   const Item1 = sequelize.define('item1', {})
   const Item2 = sequelize.define('item2', {})
   const Relation = sequelize.define('relation', {})

   Item2.belongsToMany(Item1, { through: Relation })

   Item1.hasMany(Relation, {foreignKey1, constraints: false});
   Relation.belongsTo(Item1, {foreignKey1, constraints: false});

   Item2.hasMany(Relation, {foreignKey2, constraints: false});
   Relation.belongsTo(Item2, {foreignKey2, constraints: false});

   const data = await Item1.findOne({
       where: { id: id1 },
       include: [
           {
               model: Relation,
               attributes: [],
               required: true,
               include: [
                   {
                       model: Item2,
                       attributes: [],
                       required: true,
                       where: { item2Id: id2 }
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   });
   ```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. But it isn't obvious to me how is your code snippet better than what is provided in the question. Apart from more verbose declarations, I see you use `required: true` twice. In my example I do not use it twice as there are foreign key constraints and if there's a record in the intermediate table, we can be sure the linked rows exist.

Comment: @DmytroY. Excuse me, I thought that you pass empty array in `include[].attributes` and it does not work. I can delete my answer. This sample query is more flexible.